# How in laravel 7 notifications to use Multiple Mail Driver?

Tags: laravel, notifications

In laravel 7 app I use notifications for email sending, like:

```
$newUser->notify(new SignupActivate($newUser, $site_name, $app_url));
```

Where app/Notifications/SignupActivate.php has :

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;

class SignupActivate extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    private $registeredUser;
    private $site_name;
    private $app_url;
    public function __construct($registeredUser, $site_name, $app_url)
    {
        $this->registeredUser= $registeredUser;
        $this->site_name= $site_name;
        $this->app_url= $app_url;
    }

    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        ...
```

And with mail returned in via method.
If there is a way to use Multiple Mail Driver in this Notification?
Which useally used as :

```
Mail::mailer('noreply')
        ->to($request->user())
        ->send(new PostUpdated($post));
```

Laravel Framework 7.11.0

**modified block :**
On config/mail.php I set 2 mailers :

```
<?php

return [


    'default' => env('MAIL_MAILER', 'sendgrid'),


    'mailers' => [
        'mailtrap' => [
           ...
        ],

        'sendgrid' => [
           ...
        ],


    ],
   ...
```

They both work ok if to change value in 'default'

But making in app/Notifications/SignupActivate.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;

class SignupActivate extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    private $registeredUser;
    private $site_name;
    private $app_url;
    public function __construct($registeredUser, $site_name, $app_url)
    {
        $this->registeredUser= $registeredUser;
        $this->site_name= $site_name;
        $this->app_url= $app_url;
    }

    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {

        return (new MailMessage)
            ->mailer('mailtrap') // ‘sendgrid’ does not work, 
            // if to enter some invalid value - it does not raise error - just ignored
            ->subject('Registration at ' . $this->site_name)
            ->line('Thanks for signup at '.$this->site_name.'!')
            ->line('To use our site, you must confirm your account at first.')
            ->action('Follow to Confirm Account', $url)
            ->line('Thank you for using our '.$this->site_name.' site !');
    }

    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```

What is wrong ? Seems I did like in docs...

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you can do something like this `return (new MailMessage)
                ->mailer('noreply')
                ->line('...');` on the `toMail()` method. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/notifications#customizing-the-mailer

Comment: Thank you for the link, but it does not work for me.
Please look at modified :

Answer (score 0):

digging deeper into Laravel Code (`vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/MailManager.php`) you can read:

```
/**
 * Get the mail connection configuration.
 *
 * @param  string  $name
 * @return array
 */
protected function getConfig(string $name)
{
    // Here we will check if the "driver" key exists and if it does we will use
    // the entire mail configuration file as the "driver" config in order to
    // provide "BC" for any Laravel <= 6.x style mail configuration files.
    return $this->app['config']['mail.driver']
        ? $this->app['config']['mail']
        : $this->app['config']["mail.mailers.{$name}"];
}
```

when config/mail.php contains "driver" key getConfig returns always the 'mail' value.
Removing "driver" configuration in config/mail.php will solve your problem.